# Authenticate and log in users

Tags: php, authentication

How can I improve my login script and how to check for any possible injection?

PS. the script must run on multiple platforms, so I need empty arrays for cases such as the Android ones.

### user_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_type | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### student_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `student_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| user_type | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### teacher_table:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `teacher_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DEPARTMENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| Class | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| DEPARTMENT | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### management_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `management_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DEPARTMENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`HEAD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| Class | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| DEPARTMENT | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| HEAD | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### user_status table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_status` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| Login_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_token | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_status | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### login script:

```
<?php

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // echo $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    exit;

 }else{

    $db_name ="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";

  try{ 

    $PDO = new PDO($db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    //echo "connection success";

 }catch (PDOException $error){

    //echo "connection error";
    exit;

 }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
      SELECT student_table.user_id ,student_table.user_pass
      FROM student_table
      WHERE student_table.user_email = :EMAIL
      UNION 
      SELECT
      teacher_table.user_id ,teacher_table.user_pass
      FROM teacher_table
      WHERE teacher_table.user_email = :EMAIL
      UNION 
      SELECT
      management_table.user_id ,management_table.user_pass
      FROM management_table
      WHERE management_table.user_email = :EMAIL
      " );

 $stmt->bindParam(':EMAIL', $email);
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 if (!empty($row)) {

 if (password_verify($pass, $row['user_pass'])) {

 function guidv4($data = null) {
 $data = $data ?? random_bytes(16);
 assert(strlen($data) == 16);
 $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);
 $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);
 return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 
 4));
 }

 $user_id = $row['user_id'];
 $user_online = 'ONLINE';
 $user_token = guidv4();

 $sql_insert = "
 INSERT INTO user_status 
 (user_id, user_token,user_status) 
 VALUES 
 (:ID,:TOKEN,:ONLINE ); ";

 $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_insert);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $user_id);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ONLINE', $user_online);
 $stmt->bindParam(':TOKEN', $user_token);
 $stmt->execute();

 $sql_select ="
 SELECT user_table.user_type 
 FROM user_table 
 WHERE user_table.user_id = :USER_ID";

 $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_select);
 $stmt->bindParam(':USER_ID', $user_id);
 $stmt->execute();
 $row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

 foreach ($row2 as $key ) {

 $user_id = $row['user_id'];

 if ($key == 'STUDENT') {

 $stmt2 = $PDO->prepare("
 SELECT
 student_table.user_type,
 user_status.login_id,
 user_status.user_token 
 FROM  student_table
 LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status.user_id = 
 student_table.user_id
 WHERE  student_table.user_id = :USERID 
 "); 

 $stmt2->bindParam(':USERID', $user_id);
 if ($stmt2->execute()) {
 $row3 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Log_In_Success', 
              'user' =>$row2['user_type'],
              'type' => $row3['user_type'],
              'id' => $row3['login_id'],  
              'token' => $row3['user_token']);
               echo json_encode($returnApp);
              
          }
          
            }if ($key == 'TEACHER') {
                
                  $stmt3 = $PDO->prepare("
                                SELECT
                                       teacher_table.Class,
                                       teacher_table.DEPARTMENT,
                                       user_status.login_id,
                                       user_status.user_token 
                                FROM  teacher_table
                                LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status.user_id = teacher_table.user_id
                                WHERE  teacher_table.user_id = :USERID 
                                
                              "); 

              $stmt3->bindParam(':USERID', $user_id);

              if ($stmt3->execute()) {
              $row4 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
              $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Log_In_Success', 
              'user' =>$row2['user_type'],
              'CL' =>$row4['Class'],
              'DEP' => $row4['DEPARTMENT'],
              'id' => $row4['login_id'],  
              'token' => $row4['user_token']);
               echo json_encode($returnApp);
              }
          }if ($key == 'MANAGEMENT'){
                
                  $stmt4 = $PDO->prepare("
                                SELECT
                                       management_table.CLASS,
                                       management_table.DEPARTMENT,
                                       management_table.HEAD,
                                       user_status.login_id,
                                       user_status.user_token 
                                FROM  management_table
                                LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status .user_id = management_table.user_id
                                WHERE  management_table.user_id = :USERID 
                                
                              "); 

              $stmt4->bindParam(':USERID', $user_id);

              if ($stmt4->execute()) {
              $row5 = $stmt4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
              $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Log_In_Success', 
              'user' =>$row2['user_type'],
              'CL' =>$row5['CLASS'],
              'DEP' => $row5['DEPARTMENT'],
              'HD' => $row5['HEAD'],
              'id' => $row5['login_id'],  
              'token' => $row5['user_token']);
               echo json_encode($returnApp);   
       }    
      }
     }
    }else {       
     $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Log_In_Failed');
     echo json_encode($returnApp);
    }
   } else {
     $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Email_Doesnt_Exist');
     echo json_encode($returnApp);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hello at Code Review@SE. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The least troublesome way to present code is to use *code fences*: two lines containing just `~~~`, and paste the code between.

Comment: @greybeard so do you want me to divide code ? cause i cannot find anything in how do i ask a good question ? article that clashes with the question

Comment: I want *actual, working code from a project, with enough context to give useful advice, in a question titled for what the code is to accomplish*. I find it hard to believe your tables are named `tableA`,  `tableB`,  `tableC`.

Comment: @greybeard okay ill change the table name .. but just to be clear its 14 different tables and i had to cut it to three so it would be readable

Comment: so most of my tables are 2 or 3 initials .. i hope writing each one in full name isnt a problem so it would be easy to recognize @greybeard and thank you for the tip

Comment: That's the difference between Stack Overflow and Code Review: Stack Overflow wants a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example (strip everything that seems unrelated to the problem), where Code Review requires code to be as close to the original as possible for the best reviews. It confuses a lot of new people.

Comment: Everyone here is just trying to help and to determine whether we can actually help you or not. It may seem unfriendly perhaps (even though it isn't), but it's essential to salvage questions to their best possible state for the best answers (or to be able to give a proper answer at all).

Comment: Old questions are not necessarily up to standards, so please don't use those as an example to use in a "they were allowed to do this there so why is everyone complaining now". We simply can't be everywhere at once and sometimes the rules change over time. We like to think we got wiser over the years. People are not having a bad day, they're trying to help.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about your code is that that you use prepared statements with bound variables. Too often we see input variables in query strings.

Also nice is the use of the `filter_var()` function instead of a complex regular expression.

But that's where the good things end. You haven't properly indented the code, which makes it hard to read. And hard to read it is. This is a very complex piece of code with lots of nested `if` ...`else` ... and `exit`. To illustrate this point; This is what the structure of your code looks like:

```
if (....) {
    exit;
} else {
    try { 
    } catch (....) {
        exit;
    }
    if (....) {
        if (....) {
            function name(....) 
            {
                return ....;
            }
            foreach (....) {
                if (....) {
                    if (....) {
                    }
              
                }
                if (....) {
                    if (....) {
                    }
                }
                if (....) {
                    if (....) {
                    }    
                }
            }
        } else {       
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Even when properly indented, and without most of the code, it is difficult to understand. The *technical term* for this type of code is: [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). It is difficult to understand and harder to maintain.

That is, I have to say, **the biggest security risk** here.

Another problem, also caused by the lack of structure, is that there's quite a bit of repetition of code. See: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I count five `echo json_encode($returnApp);`. You have four select queries, going through the same routine every time. You could create a function for that. Something like:

```
function retrieveData($db, $query, $parameters = [])
{
    $statement = $db->prepare($query); 
    foreach ($parameters as $placeholder => $value) {
        $statement->bindValue($placeholder, $value);
    }
    $data = null;
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Or any variant thereof. The basic idea is to encapsulate things you do repeatedly in an easy to read, and therefore easy to understand, function. On top of that you can much better test this function in isolation, than you can with code that is embedded in other code. Note that I even made the function more powerful than you actually need right now: It can cope with multiple parameters and output multiple rows.

I challenge you to restructure your code so you only need one `echo json_encode($returnApp);` and you don't have any `if` blocks, nested deeper than 1 level, anymore. Use functions for this. You'll find that your code will be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: i accepted your challege and updated my script .. no nested if ,used functions, one echo for error and another one for success .. i know its not perfect but i hope its much better than the old one .. tested and works perfect

Comment: @TaaLee Yes, it is better. I still have a few tips. Try to [get your indentation under control](https://youtu.be/lT8N85DRzZQ). Also, try to keep similar code together. That means all the functions together, and all the control code together. Don't put functions in the middle of other code. Always try to make your code as easy to read, and understand, as possible. You will thank your younger self for it in the future.

Comment: A correction on the link I gave in my previous comment. I don't agree with the requirement to use tabs instead of spaces. The width of tabs is not defined and depends on your editor. The argument that it would "take longer to process spaces" is nonsense. I agree a tab is easier to remove than spaces, but since you cannot see the difference between tabs and spaces, it's always a surprise what happens in code littered with tabs. I'm not making this up, it's part of the PHP Standards Recommendations, and for good reasons. See: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#24-indenting

Comment: Please refrain from suggestions on updated code. The OP should have created a new post. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).